# "Прощай" и "до свидания" — есть ли разница?

Tags: выбор-слов, этикет

Я бы сказала, что "прощай" говорят, когда прощаются навсегда, а "до свидания", соответственно, — на время. Но можно ли сказать "прощай", если расстаешься не насовсем?

Answer (score 1):

В "**Прощай!**" вкладывается смысл просьбы простить за прошлое и прощать после, - даже тогда, когда о человеке, которого долго не будет рядом, доходят какие-либо не вполне ясные сведения, то есть просьбы верить в него.